# md5 and salting password best practice

Tags: python, passwords, md5, salt

I've built a simple RESTful API in Python, using Flask.
There is a front-end which connects to the api, for instance if a user logs in or performs some functionality which requires data from the back-end.

Currently, I only md5(password) from the front-end to the api. If a user logs in, I encapsulate their password in md5 at the front-end, and the api will send a query to the database, comparing the md5(password) that is saved against the username.

I read something that might be helpful for me in that I can use the Python package bcrypt to salt passwords, reducing brute force attempts.

Just a general question for the approach, but do you need to md5 a salted password, or is it a good practice to first md5 a password, and then add salt when storing it in the database?

When a user logs in, I don't want to send a plain text password, which is why I send what they provide as md5 to the api.

Comment: This is already a bad design. Password hashing needs to happen server-side - the unhashed password should be protected in transit by an encrypted connection, not by hashing. With your design, the hash you send is the real password, and hashing does not provide the protection it's supposed to provide.

Comment: Also, md5 is not appropriate for password hashing. (It's hard to call it appropriate for anything these days, but especially not password hashing.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica so should the front-end be sending the real password just in plain text, at which point the back-end is handing hashing? Can the API not handle hashing?